# Javascript splice not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I may be wrong on what I think .splice() is meant to do, but I thought it removed one element of an array.  All I want to do here is remove "pears", but it doesn't work:

```
var my_array = ["apples","pears","bananas","oranges"];

my_array.splice($.inArray("pears",my_array));

$.each(my_array, function(k,v) {
    document.write(v+"<br>");
});
```

Also at http://jsfiddle.net/jdb1991/nV95v/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing two arguments:

- [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) wants the second argument to be the subject array
- [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) accepts a second argument to specify the number of elements to be deleted

The code becomes:

```
var my_array = ["apples","pears","bananas","oranges"];

my_array.splice($.inArray("pears", my_array), 1);

$.each(my_array, function(k,v) {
    document.write(v+"<br>");
});
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/nV95v/1/)

Answer (score 4):

```
var my_array = ["apples","pears","bananas","oranges"];

my_array.splice($.inArray("pears", my_array), 1);

$.each(my_array, function(k,v) {
    document.write(v+"<br>");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

this works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HbjHV/

```
var my_array = ["apples","pears","bananas","oranges"];

var pos = $.inArray("pears", my_array);
pos !== -1 && my_array.splice(pos, 1);

$.each(my_array, function(k,v) {
    document.write(v+"<br>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the array to $.inArray and also pass the number of elements to remove into array.splice:

```
var my_array = ["apples","pears","bananas","oranges"];

my_array.splice($.inArray("pears", my_array), 1);

$.each(my_array, function(k,v) {
    document.write(v+"<br>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/nV95v/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
my_array.splice($.inArray("pears", my_array), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You fogot the array:

```
$.inArray("pears",my_array)
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 0):

Please look [what arguments](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) `.splice()` method does recieve!