# JavaScript slice not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to clone my array and then delete one element from it by using the slice() function. However, whenever I click on the element I want to be deleted, it deletes everything in the array except for the one that I click.

Here is my current code:

```
deleteContact(contacts: Contacts){
if (contacts === null || contacts === undefined) {
  return;
}

const pos = this.contacts.indexOf(contacts);
if (pos < 0) {
  return;
}

this.contacts = this.contacts.splice(pos, 1);
this.contactsListClone = this.contacts.slice();
this.contactListChangedEvent.next(this.contactsListClone);
}
```

Comment: You are removing all the items except one from `contacts` *before* cloning it.  Also, your question says you're using `slice`, but your code uses `splice`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript splice not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077231/javascript-splice-not-working)

Answer (score 11):

`splice` returns **deleted elements**, so `this.contacts` has only one deleted elements after this line

```
this.contacts = this.contacts.splice(pos, 1);
```

simply make it

```
this.contacts.splice(pos, 1);
```